# The sensors don't send correct data

Tags: arduino-nano, adafruit

I try to make a weather station, but I don't understand why it doesn't work. I had tried to read a lot of the sensors but I doesn't find my errors.

[image]

The code:

```
 #include "DHT.h"
 #include "SFE_BMP180.h"
 #include "Wire.h"
 #include "MQ135.h"
 #include "SPI.h"
 #include "Adafruit_GFX.h"
 #include "Adafruit_ILI9341.h"
```

#define DHTPIN 2
 #define DHTTYPE DHT11
 DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);

SFE_BMP180 bmp180;
 double PresionNivelMar=1013.25;

int UVOUT = A3;
 int REF_3V3 = A1;

#define PIN_MQ135 A0
 MQ135 mq135_sensor = MQ135(PIN_MQ135);

#define TFT_DC 9
 #define TFT_CS 10
 Adafruit_ILI9341 tft = Adafruit_ILI9341(TFT_CS, TFT_DC);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  dht.begin();
  if (bmp180.begin())
          Serial.println("BMP180 iniciado correctamenten");
        else {
          Serial.println("Error al iniciar el BMP180");
        }
  pinMode(UVOUT, INPUT);
  pinMode(REF_3V3, INPUT);

tft.begin();
  tft.setRotation(0);
  tft.fillScreen(ILI9341_BLACK); 
  tft.setTextColor(ILI9341_DARKGREEN);
  tft.setTextSize(2);
  tft.setCursor(70,20);
  tft.print("S.E.M.S.");
  tft.setTextSize(1);
  tft.setTextColor(ILI9341_WHITE);
  tft.setCursor(20,310);
  tft.print("Colegio Panamericana");
  tft.setTextSize(1.5);
}

void loop() {
  char a;
  double T,P,A;
  float h = dht.readHumidity();
  float t = dht.readTemperature();
  float rzero = mq135_sensor.getRZero();
  float correctedRZero = mq135_sensor.getCorrectedRZero(t, h);
  float resistance = mq135_sensor.getResistance();
  float correctedresistence = mq135_sensor.getCorrectedResistance(t, h);
  float ppm = mq135_sensor.getPPM();
  float correctedPPM = mq135_sensor.getCorrectedPPM(t, h);

Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Temperatura: ");
  Serial.print(t);
  Serial.print(" °C ");
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Humedad: ");
  Serial.print(h);
  Serial.print(" %RH");
  Serial.println();

a = bmp180.startTemperature();
  if (a != 0) {
    delay(a);
    a = bmp180.getTemperature(T);
     if (a != 0) {
         a = bmp180.startPressure(3);
        if (a != 0) {
                  delay(a);
                        a = bmp180.getPressure(P,T);
                 if (a != 0) {
                  A= bmp180.altitude(P,PresionNivelMar);
                 }
              }
           }
       }

Serial.print("Temperatura: ");
  Serial.print(T);
  Serial.print(" °C , ");
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Presion: ");
  Serial.print(P);
  Serial.print(" mb"); 
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Altitud: ");
  Serial.print(A);
  Serial.print(" m s.n.m.");
  Serial.println();

int uvLevel = averageAnalogRead(UVOUT);
  int refLevel = averageAnalogRead(REF_3V3);
  float outputVoltage = 3.3 / refLevel * uvLevel;
  float uvIntensity = mapfloat(outputVoltage, 0.99, 2.8, 0.0, 15.0);

Serial.print("Output: ");
  Serial.print(refLevel);
  Serial.print(" v");
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("ML8511 output: ");
  Serial.print(uvLevel);
  Serial.print(" v");
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("ML8511 voltage: ");
  Serial.print(outputVoltage);
  Serial.print(" v");
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("UV Intensity (mW/cm^2): ");
  Serial.print(uvIntensity);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("MQ135 RZero: ");
  Serial.print(rzero);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Corregido RZero: ");
  Serial.print(correctedRZero);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Resistance: ");
  Serial.print(resistance);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Corregido Resistencia: ");
  Serial.print(correctedresistence);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("PPM: ");
  Serial.print(ppm);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Corregido PPM: ");
  Serial.print(correctedPPM);
  Serial.println("ppm");
  Serial.println();

escribir(14,40,1,"ILI9341_GREEN","Temperatura");
  escribir(14,60,0.6,"ILI9341_RED",String(t));
  escribir(14,60,0.6,"ILI9341_RED","°C");
  escribir(14,80,1,"ILI9341_GREEN","Humedad");
  escribir(14,100,0.6,"ILI9341_BLUE",String(h));
  escribir(14,100,0.6,"ILI9341_BLUE","%RH");
  escribir(14,120,1,"ILI9341_GREEN","Presión");
  escribir(14,140,0.6,"ILI9341_LIGHTGREY",String(P));
  escribir(14,140,0.6,"ILI9341_LIGHTGREY","psi");
  escribir(14,160,1,"ILI9341_GREEN","Calidad del Aire");
  escribir(14,180,0.6,"ILI9341_CYAN",String(correctedPPM));
  escribir(14,180,0.6,"ILI9341_CYAN","ppm");
  escribir(14,200,1,"ILI9341_GREEN","Radiación UV");
  escribir(14,220,0.6,"ILI9341_MAGENTA",String(uvIntensity));
  escribir(14,220,0.6,"ILI9341_MAGENTA","mW/cm^2");
}

int averageAnalogRead(int pinToRead) {
  byte numberOfReadings = 8;
  unsigned int runningValue = 0; 
  for(int x = 0 ; x < numberOfReadings ; x++)
          runningValue += analogRead(pinToRead);
          runningValue /= numberOfReadings;
    return(runningValue);
}

float mapfloat(float x, float in_min, float in_max, float out_min, float out_max) {
  return (x - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min;
}

void escribir(int X,int Y, int tam, short color, String mensaje){
  tft.setCursor(X,Y);
  tft.setTextSize(tam);
  tft.setTextColor(color);
  tft.print(mensaje);
}

Also I adds a little screen.

I make this:

[image]

Sorry for the size, the original image was too heavy to upload, in addition to the disorder.

I bought on: naylampmechatronics.com . 
And I used his information.
And I read a bit of adafruit.com

Comment: In your fritzing drawing, use color coding with red=+, black=- and others when appropriate. Just using blue is to hard to figure out for me so I don't.

Comment: Some solderless breadbord have the power rail slit into two parts, left side and right side, check if that is the case.

Comment: i don't see the resistor for your raw DHT11.

Comment: Do you think it might help instead of just saying "I can't find the errors" to actually tell us what it does that is wrong or what errors you see?  Are we supposed to look at this and guess what it does and guess what you wanted it to do?

Comment: @MatsK I'm sorry for that.

Comment: @MatsK I tried to prove other form to connect the sensors.

Comment: @Delta_G I'm sorry but I tried to told I can't find the errors with the connections and the program because its doesn't work correct. Also I'm a beginner.

Comment: But you can tell us what are the symptoms right?  Look, you have some code and it does something.  You want it to do something else.  How can we help you if we don't know what those two things are?  You can draw a better schematic can't you?  There's lot you can do without knowing the exact error in your code to help us help you.  Something like, "I expect the light to come on when I press the button but it doesn't."  Does that make sense?

Comment: @dandavis My dht11 have a little board-controller with which I only connect direct.

Comment: @Delta_G sorry again, the dht11 sensor does not send data, the sensor bmp180 if it measures the pressure, but to correct it uses the dht11, so it does not correct, besides the ML8511 gives erroneous data, the mq135 if it works well but also corrects with the dht11, so it does not work well when corrected.

Comment: @Delta_G  I will make a new fritzing drawing.

Comment: OK.  Still waiting on that schematic.  Did you notice the comment by @dandavis?  Sounds like your main issue is with the dht11 and he spotted an issue with that.  Do you think you should address that issue?

Comment: NOT FRITZING.  They're impossible to decipher.  Just draw a schematic.

Comment: @Delta_G Yes, because I cannot see my errors. Fritzing I only use how place to draw the connections.

Comment: @Delta_G I have to changed a little of the post. Thanks for your tips.

Comment: Fritzing is the only way you know?  You don't know how to use a pencil and paper?

Comment: @Delta_G Jajajajaja, I have left all my materials at school.

Comment: The method for troubleshooting is: 1. Disconnect everything. 2. Add **one** sensor. 3. Verify if the sensor works. 4. If it works repeat step 2 for next sensor. 5 If it doesn't work, why? is it the connections correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method for troubleshooting is:

1. Disconnect everything.
2. Add one sensor.
3. Verify if the sensor works.
4. If it works repeat step 2 for next sensor.
5. If it doesn't work, why? is it the connections correct?